# Is there a way to download the tarball once using cmake

Tags: cmake

Im build libjpeg as external project. Its build normally.
Here projects folder structure:

```
${SOURCE_DIR}/
  ${SOME_BUILD_DIR}/
    externals/
      jpeg-9a/
      jpeg-pre/
  externals/
    jpeg-9a/
    jpeg-overlay/
      CMakeLists.txt
  tarballs/
    jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz
  CMakeLists.txt
```

But tarball downloaded and unpacked again if I start building project from zero.

In other words I clean `${SOME_BUILD_DIR}/`. At next build cmake do the next:

1. download `tarballs/jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz`
2. unpack libjpeg into `externals/jpeg-9a`
3. copy `externals/jpeg-overlay/CMakeLists.txt` into `externals/jpeg-9a`
4. build libjpeg in `${SOME_BUILD_DIR}/externals/jpeg-9a/`

Actually first 3 points can be omitted. But my interest only in first action. Is there way to prevent extra download?

Here is my `${SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
include(ExternalProject)

set(EXTERNALS_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/externals)

set(JPEG_VERSION "9a")
set(JPEG_URI http://ijg.org/files/jpegsrc.v${JPEG_VERSION}.tar.gz)
set(JPEG_DIR ${EXTERNALS_DIR}/jpeg-${JPEG_VERSION})

ExternalProject_Add(
    jpeg
    STAMP_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/externals/jpeg-pre
    BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/externals/jpeg-${JPEG_VERSION}
    URL ${JPEG_URI}
    SOURCE_DIR ${JPEG_DIR}
    DOWNLOAD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tarballs
    CMAKE_ARGS ""
    UPDATE_COMMAND cmake -E copy_directory ${EXTERNALS_DIR}/jpeg-${JPEG_VERSION}-overlay/. ${JPEG_DIR}
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    TEST_COMMAND ""
)
```

See https://github.com/anton-sergeev/cmake_externalproject for details.

Answer (score 0):

You should not place generated files in the source tree.

In your case, the problematic line is `DOWNLOAD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tarballs`. A cleaner approach would be to place the download in a directory in the binary dir and compile from there. Now, of course that means that when wiping the build directory it will also wipe the downloaded sources. Which kind of solves the problem of having to download a file that you already had, although probably not in the way you would have liked.

The thing is, this is by design. Wiping the binary dir is conceptually equivalent to telling CMake to start over from scratch. There is no point in trying to reuse stuff in this case because, well, you want to start from scratch. The correct workflow to enable reusing with CMake is simply: Do not wipe the build directory. Instead rely on `make clean` to enforce full rebuilds and only wipe the build directory if you want to perform a full reconfigure of CMake.

The only clean way to avoid redownload is to move the download out of the `ExternalProject` command. For instance, you could place the extracted files into the source tree and check them in as part of the project. Or have them downloaded by a custom `execute_process` command which implements the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanx. Actually I ran into this problem in project that builds for multiply platforms (lin32/lin64/mingw). Tarball downloads once for each build.
Ill try to add separate target for downloading tarball as you suggested.

Comment: Done. [Here is CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/anton-sergeev/cmake_externalproject/blob/b3ef26fe616ac98a3b3eeb86a6b33add0765cacf/CMakeLists.txt) with separate target for downloading. Thanx @ComicSansMS.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `md5 jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz`, you can use the outputted hash with the ExternalProject URL_MD5 option.

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    jpeg
    STAMP_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/externals/jpeg-pre
    BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/externals/jpeg-${JPEG_VERSION}
    URL ${JPEG_URI}
    URL_MD5 <md5_hash_of_downloaded_file>
    SOURCE_DIR ${JPEG_DIR}
    DOWNLOAD_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tarballs
    CMAKE_ARGS ""
    UPDATE_COMMAND cmake -E copy_directory ${EXTERNALS_DIR}/jpeg-${JPEG_VERSION}-overlay/. ${JPEG_DIR}
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    TEST_COMMAND ""
)
```